# Caliburn.Micro Go Back called in On Activate not working in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, caliburn.micro, caliburn

This question is specific to Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT); it may also be applicable Windows 8.1. I am using Caliburn.Micro 2.0.1

**In my ViewModel's `OnActivate` I check whether an item is a database, if it isn't, I want to navigate back to the previous page.**

The simplist solution will be just to call `GoBack` in the `OnActivate` method (this works in Windows Phone 8.0):

```
INavigationService _navigationService;
protected override void OnActivate()
{
    _item = GetItemFromDB();
    if(_item == null)
    {
       _navigationService.GoBack() 
    }
}
```

To navigate to the view model I call:

```
_navigationService.NavigateToViewModel<MyViewModel>(_param);
```

But it does not work, it ignores the `GoBack` call and stays on the page which I do not want to view.

When stepping through the code you can see that the `GoBack` code is called inside the `NavigateToViewModel` method; I expect this is the reason why it does not work (something to do with a queuing issue maybe?).

I have a very *"hacky"* solution that involves a timer (that works), but I really despise it since it is prone to threading issues and has the possibility of being called during the `NavigateToViewModel` call (if it takes long to finish), which will then again not work:

```
protected override void OnActivate()
{
    _item = GetItemFromDB();
    if(_item == null)
    {
        DispatcherTimer navigateBackTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        navigateBackTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
        navigateBackTimer.Tick += GoBackAfterNavigation;
        navigateBackTimer.Start();
    }
}

public void GoBackAfterNavigation(object sender, object e)
{
    _navigationService.GoBack();
    (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
}
```

Is there a better way to navigate back? Why doesn't the `GoBack` work in `OnActivate`? Is there a way to get it to work in `OnActivate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Execute.OnUIThreadAsync(() => /* navigationCode */);
```

instead of a timer to queue the action immediately after the processing of the current stack has finished.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Why does it work, can you please explain. Is it the async, or the UI thread?

Comment: Obviously, there is a problem in WP8.1 when you are currently navigating and trying to navigate there. This seems to be a bug in caliburn.micro.  The code uses the Dispatcher to put your navigation call behind the current executing code.